# jquery function not working onClick?

Tags: jquery, click

i have a jquery script:

```
    $.get('php/username.php', { username: userName },
    function(data){
        var get_back = data;
        alert(get_back);
    });
```

what happes is that if i run it in firebug console it works, but if i add it inside a click function, it doesnt:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btnLogout").click(function () {
    $.get('php/username.php', { username: userName },
    function(data){
        var get_back = data;
        alert(get_back);
    });
});
});
```

html

```
<p><input type="submit" name="btnLogout" id="btnLogout"  value="Logout" class="page"/></p>
```

i don't understand.

thanks

Comment: Can you post your HTML markup? And make sure you attach the click handler once the DOM is ready - perhaps in `$(document).ready();`

Comment: updated. and  i use `$(document).ready()`

Comment: Please see my updated answer - your type should be changed from `submit` to `button` unless you have compelling reason not to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

You're using an `input` of type `submit` - change it to `type="button"` instead - a submit button already has default functionality (when inside of a `<form>`) that you will need to stop by using `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropogation()` - see below:

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnLogout").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //stop the submit event for the submit button
        $.get('php/get_username.php', { username: userName },
        function(data){
            var get_back = data;
            alert(get_back);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){` is there. still no difference

Answer (score 2):

Try `$("#btnLogout").submit(function(){...})` instead

Comment: `.live` doesn't seem to make a difference

Comment: Since input is a submit, Try the `submit()` event handler. Check updated answer